# let object in an array call a variable without if statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

rawData is an array and for every instance in the array there are two objects: row[0] (coincell) and row1.  There are six different values that coincell could be and for each value of coincell, I want to sum all instances of that specific value.  I know I can do 6 different if, else if, etc.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?  Something like the code pasted below where I could let the coincell object in the array instance reference that particular variable?  BTW prefer something that can work in GAS

```
  var BTC = 0;
  var BCH = 0;
  var LTC = 0;
  var ZEC = 0;
  var DASH = 0;
  var BTCP = 0;
  var XVG = 0;
  for(i in rawData){
    var row = rawData[i];
    var coincell = row[0];
    var amtcell = row[1];
    Logger.log(coin)
    coincell += amtcell;
```

Comment: Use the `for ... in` pattern only for object property enumeration, not array iteration. Please clarify how you know what type of coin `coincell` is if it is also numeric and can be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I would do a most dynamic way to handle this, for example this would create an object with all the currencies and their sums and it will work if you add more and more coins.

```js
const coinsArray = [
['BTC', 100],
['BCH', 150],
['BTC', 100],
['ZEC', 100],
['BCH', 520],
['DASH', 100],
['DASH', 250],
['BTC', 200],
]

const coinsCount = {};

coinsArray.forEach(coin=>{
    if(!coinsCount[coin[0]]){
        coinsCount[coin[0]] = 0;
    }
    coinsCount[coin[0]] += coin[1];
})


console.log(coinsCount);
```

Comment: The more appropriate method to use when iterating through an array to produce a variable is to use `reduce`. Also, don't use `let` unless you're deliberately reassigning a variable, which you should avoid - use `const` by default instead.

Comment: `let` is invalid syntax in Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

## Creating an object with values and a sum method

**First I created a function for creating my object which isn't exactly what you asked for but it's close and it contains a sum method.**

```
function makeMyObject(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) {
  return {value1:v1,value2:v2,value3:v3,value4:v4,value5:v5,sum:function(){return this.value1+this.value2+this.value3+this.value4+this.value5;}};
}
```

**Then I created this spreadsheet for loading values into my objects:**

[image]

**Then I created this function for loading the objects into any array of objects**

```
function loadData(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ObjectData');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var myObjA=[];
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    myObjA=makeMyObject(vA[i][0],vA[i][1],vA[i][2],vA[i][3],vA[i][4]);
    vA[i][5]=myObjA.sum();//object is created above and I call the sum method to put the value into vA[i][5] which is the sum column.  vA[i][5] was  created because there is a header element in that column and getDataRange always return a rectangular range so the last column elements are empty but they are there ready to accept data.
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);//write the data into the range to show the sums
}
```

**The spreadsheet after running load data**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple associative object, i.e. a key-value pairing:

```
var sums = {
  BTC: 0,
  ...
};
```

If a cell in the row identifies which coin you are working with, then it is extremely easy to return the current sum. You could extend this to design to track additional information (e.g. store the values and also the average, etc.)

An example, where the coin type is in column A, and the coin count is in column B:

```
function tallySheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("name");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sums = {};
  for(var r = 0; r < values.length; ++r) {
    var coinType = values[r][0];
    if(!sums[coinType]) {
      sums[coinType] = 0;
    }
    sums[coinType] += values[r][1];
  }
  console.log(sums);
}
```